# exclude section using not()

Tags: html, css

My CSS code for the Paragraph tag has to affect all the p tags in my webpage except the p tag in footer. what should i do? I tried this

```css
.mypage section :not(footer) p{color:red}
```

```html
<body class="mypage">
<section>
<p>Hello world</p>
</section>
<footer>
<p>footer content</p>
</footer>
</body>
```

Actually my CSS code should not affect p tag inside the footer. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Footer` is not inside a section element, so your selector won't work.

```css
.mypage :not(footer) p{
   color:red
}
```

```html
<body class="mypage">
<section>
<p>Hello world</p>
</section>
<footer>
<p>footer content</p>
</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not target the footer again ?

```
.mypage section p{color: red}
.mypage footer p{color: blue}

<body class="mypage">
    <section>
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>footer content</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: did you try this ? i guess no ... there is no class on footer and footer is not inside a section